# How to Completely Remove an Application with it's PPA that is being installed via PPA and GPG

Tags: command-line, linux-mint, package-management

I installed brave browser using:

```
sudo curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main"|sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list
sudo apt update && sudo apt install brave-browser
```

Now I want to remove it **completely**.

One [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1250197) suggests using:

```
sudo apt remove brave-browser brave-keyring
sudo apt purge brave-browser
rm -rf ~/.config/BraveSoftware
rm -rf ~/.cache/BraveSoftware
```

However, it does not remove the PPA and the Key. Is there any easy solution (like `ppa-purge`) or shall I just use the following lines with the above commands.

```
sudo rm /usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list
```

To be specific, I want to know the appropriate way to remove apps (completely, with key and ppa) that is installed via this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

| Command | Opposite |
| --- | --- |
| `sudo curl [options] -o <file> <url>` | `sudo rm <file>` |
| `echo <debline> | sudo tee <file>` | `sudo rm <file>` |
| `sudo apt install <package>` | `sudo apt purge --autoremove <package>` |

So yes, the opposite is really to simply remove the files that you created in addition to purging the package and any dependencies which were installed alongside it.

You should not need to explicitly uninstall `brave-keyring`.

Answer (score 0):

Difference between using `ppa-purge` and `rm` is that `rm` will remove the ppa while `ppa-purge` disable it. Disable means the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list` will still exist, but all lines will be commented, i.e. # will be appended in front of them. If you want to enable it, you have to uncomment them.

On removing gpg key, your method is right. However, you can use `apt-key` command, which is currently deprecated and won't be used after Debian 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 . `apt-key list` will show all trusted key and their owner. Distrust a existing key by `apt-key del "<key>"` . You can use entire key or last eight digit to delete it.